# Find the minimum posssible integer value of the summation

Tags: calculus, integration, summation

> Let $f(x)$ is a continuous, increasing and positive value function in the interval $[0,a]$ such that
>
> $$\int_0^af(x)dx=20$$
>
> Then find the minimum posssible integer value of the following summation
>
> $$a\left[f\left(\frac a{20}\right)+f\left(\frac {2a}{20}\right)+\cdots+f\left(\frac {20a}{20}\right)\right]$$

---

My attepmts

Let $f(x)=x$ then $\frac {a^2}{2}=20\implies a^2=40$

$$a\left[f\left(\frac a{20}\right)+f\left(\frac {2a}{20}\right)+\cdots+f\left(\frac {20a}{20}\right)\right]=a\left(\frac{21a}{2}\right)=\frac{21}{2}a^2=420$$

I know that my method is completely nonsense , but I dont know anything about the problem...

Comment: $f(x)=\frac{20}{a}$ is a lower bound and it sums to $20$..  Any increasing function can be constructed by adding a small increasing function with integral $=0$.   If $20$ doesn't work, add an increment with integral $=1$

Answer (score -1):

Let the sum be $R(a)$, and it relates to the Riemann sum of $f$. Clearly that $R(a)$ is the right R-sum of the function $f$ and since $f$ is increasing and positive, it follows that $R(a) \ge 20\displaystyle \int_{0}^a f(x)dx = 20\cdot 20 = 400$ which is the min value.

Comment: I need more backround, please..Thank you!! (+1)

Comment: You can look up the definition of $\displaystyle \int_{a}^b f(x)dx$ in any elementary real analysis book.

Comment: This is a high school problem..Can you provide a source for me, please?

Comment: Draw a picture of a rising curve from $0$ to $a$, and you can see it. You don't need a book on this.

Comment: Well, thats a lower bound, but for it to be a minimum, you need to show a function $f$ which is continuous, increasing and positive which achieves that bound.  I haven't downvoted, but its a matter of time before someone does.